# Tkinter Formatting Buttons in Same Row using .grid

Tags: python, tkinter, formatting, grid-layout

How can I display a row of buttons across the bottom of the screen using Tkinter? The number of buttons is a variable. Could be 2 or could be 10. The number of items being displayed is also a variable. In this case it's 5, but could be 2 or could be 10. I am using Tkinter and currently have a working program that outputs a grid that looks like this:

```
 -------------------------
|       |Title|           |
|Item1|         |Quantity1|
|Item2|         |Quantity2|
|Item3|         |Quantity3|
|Item4|         |Quantity4|
|                         | (Intentionally blank)
|Item5|         |Quantity5|
--------------------------  (end)
```

I am outputting like so:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
itemLabel = Label(
        window,
        text = "Item1", 
).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'w')
```

However, when I try to add buttons, I can't seem to get the formatting correct. If I do it similarly to the label, with "sticky = 'w'", then it overlaps on the left. I only have 3 columns so if I have more than 3 buttons I run out of columns. Below is my desired output (hopefully all of the buttons will be of equal width):

```
-------------------------
|       |Title|           |
|Item1|         |Quantity1|
|Item2|         |Quantity2|
|Item3|         |Quantity3|
|Item4|         |Quantity4|
|                         | (Intentionally blank)
|Item5|         |Quantity5|
--------------------------
|B#1| B#2|B#3|B#4| B#5|B#6|
--------------------------- (end)
```

Comment: If the number of columns in the top section differs from the number of columns in the bottom section, consider putting each in there own frame. Then you can grid the widgets in each frame separately.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but for radiobuttons - a variable number of options which can change, in this case updated on the click of a button.  I set the max number of columns as I spill over into more rows if need be.

```
def labelling_add_radiobutton(self):
    '''add selected values as radiobuttons for labelling'''
    # destroy any existing radiobuttons in frame
    for child in self.frame3_labelling_labels.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(child, ttk.Radiobutton):
            child.destroy()
    # label variable and create radio button
    self.checkbox_validation_output = tk.StringVar(value = '')
    num_cols = 8 # sets max number of columns, rows are variable
    for count, value in enumerate(list_of_buttons):
        row = int((count + .99) / num_cols) + 1
        col = (((row - 1) + count) - ((row - 1) * num_cols) - (row - 1)) + 1
        ttk.Radiobutton(self.frame3_labelling_labels, text = value,
                        variable = self.checkbox_validation_output, value = value,
                        style = 'UL_radiobutton.TRadiobutton').grid(column = col, row = row,
                        sticky = 'w', padx = 10, pady = 10)
```